# Recursive if-statement python

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

Hi I am new to python and trying to implement a recursive function which fills up a table, but when running by program I get the following exception

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'.

```
def cost(i, j):
    if table[i][j] == None:
        v1 = v2 = v3 = v4 = None
        if i > 0 and j > 0:
            print "case1"
            v1 = cost(i-1, j-1) + getSubCostMatrixValue(options[string1[i]], options[string2[j]])
        if i > 0 and j >= 0:
            print "case2"
            v2 = cost(i-1, j) + gapCost
        if i >= 0 and j > 0:
            print "case3"
            v3 = cost(i, j-1) + gapCost
        if i == 0 and j == 0:
            print "case4"
            v4 = 0
        print "Max:"
        print max(v1,v2,v3,v4)
        table[i][j] = max(v1,v2,v3,v4)
        return table[i][j]
```

the problem ocours i case 2 and case 3, as if the recursive call fails somehow, but i cannot find out why. I feel like it is something obvious

table is filled with None from the begining, gabCost is a int, getSubCostMatrixValue also returns an int.

Comment: fix your indentation and what is `gapCost`? how is `max()` written?

Comment: You're not *returning* anything in any of your branches. Like `return v1`...`return v2` etc.

Comment: Correct test for `None` is:  `if table[i][j] is None:`.  This is because the `==` can cause unexpected evaluations to zero or False.  I doubt that is the cause of your issue though.

Comment: gapCost is set to -5 and max is pythons build in function.

Comment: The not returning is on purpuse as i onlu want to return the largest of v1-v4 for each space in the matrix.

Comment: the overall purpuse is to compare two strings through this function and the cost represents how close the two strings match

Comment: you lack a base case for when `table[i][j] != None`, maybe you mean to  `return table[i][j]` and do the if case only in that condition, in that case just reduce one level of indentation to the final return

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Most notably, provide the shortest code needed to reproduce the problem.  Running your posted code produces no output, let alone the indicated problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your `cost()` function returns `None` for some cases. If I understand right, then this can only happen if i or j are negative. As this only occurs in cases 2 or 3, it seems to me, that your i or j are indeed floats which can be larger than 0 but smaller than 1. Could this be the case? If you provide more details on your program, someone might have a more detailed answer!?